# Receiving TypeError when using custom hook for apollo mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, apollo-client

I cannot seem to debug this problem with my Apollo mutation in my **NextJS** app.

I am getting the following error

**"TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"**

It seems to be a problem with this line of code, for which I am receiving the error type "void"is not an array type.

*const [onLogin, { loading }] = useLoginAdmin...*

From what I can see, everything checks out, so I am unsure why it is throwing this error. What am I missing?

```
import { gql, useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const LOGIN_ADMIN_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation loginAdminUser($input: LoginAdminUserInput!) {
    loginAdminUser(input: $input) {
      user {
        id
        companyID
        token
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const useLoginAdmin = (options = {}) => {
  useMutation(LOGIN_ADMIN_USER_MUTATION, options);
};
```

```
import { useAuth } from "../../hooks/utils";
import { useLoginAdmin } from "../../hooks/account";
import { AdminLogin } from "../../types/auth";


const [onLogin, { loading }] = useLoginAdmin({
    onCompleted: (data: { data: AdminLogin }) => {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    onLogin({
      variables: {
        input: { email: "newcustomer@email.com", password: "password" }
      }
    });
  };

 <button
     type="submit"
     className="p-2 w-content bg-violet-600 text-white rounded-full"
      onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSubmit();
      }}
   >
   Log in
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom hook isn't returning anything. TypeScript interprets that as `void`:

```
export const useLoginAdmin = (options = {}) => {
  useMutation(LOGIN_ADMIN_USER_MUTATION, options);
};
```

I'm not sure exactly what you intended to return from your hook based on how you're using it. Maybe you intended to just return the function itself? In that case omit the curly braces around the function.

```
export const useLoginAdmin = (options = {}) => 
  useMutation(LOGIN_ADMIN_USER_MUTATION, options);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly the solution I was looking for and something simple to miss.